# How to get value from textfield and display in textfromfield (another screen)

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm new to flutter, I trying to pass a value from textfield and when i click a button submit, display it in textformfield in another screen, my problem, I don't know the right way to get value

Some Code :
      String txt = "";
      TextEditingController controllerTxt = new TextEditingController();

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Create'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Submit'),
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                //txt = (controllerTxt.text);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/ResultPage');
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              controller: controllerTxt,
              maxLines: 5,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class _ResultPageState extends State<ResultPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text('Result'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Name :',
              ),
            ),
            new Text("${controllerTxt.text}"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same thing by passing data through the constructor

```
   Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ResultPage(controllerTxt.text)));
```

```
class ResultPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String result;
 ResultPage(this.result);
```

Comment: I delete setState

Comment: Yes you do not need setState